Implementation of WaitHandle.WaitAll via Monitor.Wait
Reading from Joel Albahari's online resource on threading he says that:

Simulating the static methods that work across a set of wait handles
is easy in simple scenarios. The equivalent of calling WaitAll is
nothing more than a blocking condition that incorporates all the flags
used in place of the wait handles:

lock (_locker)
  while (!_flag1 && !_flag2 && !_flag3...)
    Monitor.Wait (_locker);

I do not really understand how we can achieve a working replacement implementation of WaitHandle.WaitAll with Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse the same way we can for AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent(the way ManualResetEventSlim is implemented e.g.).
Does anybody have a working example implementation?

...why would you want to reimplement WaitAll?

@Dai "This can be particularly useful given that WaitAll is often unusable due to COM legacy issues."
"WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported."...
Theoretically understanding the point the author is making
